# TextField controlled controller.addListener(() gets called multiple time after using the controller.clear

Tags: android, flutter, authentication

The method `addListener()` of the TextEditingController get called multiple times after executing the `clear()` method, this will only happen if we are clearing it.

```
TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pinPutController.addListener(() {
      if (_pinPutController.text.length > 4) {
          print("Hello world");
          _pinPutController.clear();
      }
  });
}
```

When the condition in the if statement is true, the body is executed twice.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do not do checking inside the initstate, you only pass controller into it

Comment: but i create a method and pass the method inside of the addListener but i have the same result  @TryHarder

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isClear = false;

TextField(
  controller: _pinPutController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter a message",
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: () => (isClear)?_pinPutController.clear(): null,
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Change the code you wrote by adding `isClear` into it

```
TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pinPutController.addListener(() {
      if (_pinPutController.text.length > 4) {
          setState(() {
            isClear = true;
          });
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: this implementation when work you press on button but i want when this condition (_pinPutController.text.length > 4) is true clear the textfild automatic